# MonoDevelop: Failed to load http handler

Tags: asp.net, mono, monodevelop, nancy

I am running MonoDevelop on OS X to develop an ASP.NET web application using [Nancy](http://nancyfx.org/). I downloaded the `nancy.dll` file and referenced it from my web project.

Inside the `web.config` I added the line:

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" type="Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet.NancyHttpRequestHandler" path="*" />
</httpHandlers>
```

to the `system.web` section, as described in the documentation of Nancy. However, if I try to run my application, my browser comes up and I see an ASP.NET error message created by Mono that tells me that it

> Failed to load httpHandler type `Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet.NancyHttpRequestHandler'

Any idea of what I am doing wrong? Why is Mono not able to find the DLL, although it is there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it ... I had missed to also download and install the `Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet` package.

Once I did this and referenced the dll, everything works fine :-)